# Change of Basis question .

Tags: linear-algebra

Given  standard basis $B$ of $\Bbb{R}^4$ and the basis $B'=((1,2)^T,(1,1)^T)$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$ and the linear tranformation 
$f:\Bbb{R}^4 \to\Bbb{R}^2,(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^T\to(4x_1-x_4,2x_1+2x_2+2x_3-3x_4)^T$

Find a the matrix that represents this linear transformation.
So my textbook does the following

$f((1,0,0,0)^T)=(4,2)^T=-2(1,2)^T+(6)(1,1)^T$

$f((0,1,0,0)^T)=(0,2)^T=2(1,2)^T+(-2)(1,1)^T$

$f((0,0,1,0)^T)=(0,2)^T=2(1,2)^T+(-2)(1,1)^T$

$f((0,0,0,1)^T)=(-1,-3)^T=-2(1,2)^T+(1)(1,1)^T$

Thus the matrix A representing f is
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 2 & 2 & -2\\
         6 & -2 & -2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I was wondering how this works in terms of matrix multiplication,

Intuitevely 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        4 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
         2 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
sends the standard basis vectors of $\Bbb{R}^4$ to standard  basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$

So now to get the represantation of this matrix in terms of Basis B' we multiply this matrix with

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1\\
         2 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

But the results arent the same..., It turns out that multiplying with the inverse of this matrix gives the same result, Can you please explain why this happens and given an intuition ???

Comment: You've got a typo. The matrix $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 2 & 2 & -2\\
         6 & -2 & -2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ should be $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 2 & 2 & -2\\
         6 & -2 & 6 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$.

Comment: fixed the mistake thanks

Comment: I think you mean something else when you say "sends the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^4$ to standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$". A matrix like that would be, for instance, $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: but with respect to the linear transformation f ?

Comment: That phrase doesn't really make sense in this context. Can you say exactly what you mean?

Comment: Im really sorry  im not good at this topic, The question said to find the matrix representing linear transformation f given 2 Bases

Comment: Okay, wait, so what you mean is that the matrix in question is the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to the standard bases. And you want to make sense of how that relates to the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to this different basis. I think you just need to check your work carefully. I'm still seeing that typo. It could very well just be a little miscalculation.

Comment: the typo was in the calculation of $f(0,0,1,0)^T$  My question is why does multiplying the inverse of the small matrix with this matrix gives me matrix A

Comment: Well that seems answered below. The small matrix sends the standard basis to $B'$, so its inverse does the opposite. Your first matrix sends $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ written in$B'$ coordinates. To get back to standard coordinates you need to compose with the inverse of the small matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1}$ lets you to send a vector in basis $B'$ to canonical (standard) basis. Example: $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1} \pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{1 \\ 2}$, representation of first basis vector of $B'$ in canonical basis. You need just the opposite, hence the inversion.

Comment: but you are sending $(1,0)^T$ to $(1,2)^T$  doesnt this mean you convert it to B' basis ?

Comment: No. Let's take space $\mathbb{R}^1[x]$ (linear polynomials) to clearly distinguish between *vector* and its representation as a ($n \times 1$) matrix. We have canonical basis $\{e_1 = 1, e_2 = x\}$; we have basis $B' = \{b_1 = 1+2x, b_2 = 1+x\}$. We have vector $v = 1+2x$ (which is the same no matter what the basis). In basis $B'$, $v = 1b_1+0b_2 \sim (1,0)^T$. In canonical basis, $v = 1 e_1 + 2 e_2 \sim (1,2)^T$.

Comment: @asddf For the same example, if you take vector $u$ corresponding to $(1,0)^T$ in *canonical* basis, it would be $u = 1e_1+0e_2 = 1$ and its representation in $B'$ would be $u = 2b_2 - b_1 \sim (-1, 2)^T$. Note that $1 \times n$ matrix itself doesn't describe a vector, you need to keep track what basis you wrote that matrix representation in.

Comment: i think i got it , thank you